# irrelevant corrupt record in xml file, while reading it as spark DF

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read an xml file as a DF in spark.

XML file:

```
<cool>
<incollection mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/acm/kim95/Blakeley95">
<author>Jos&eacute; A. Blakeley</author>
<title>OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.</title>
<pages>69-88</pages>
<booktitle>Modern Database Systems</booktitle>
<url>db/books/collections/kim95.html#Blakeley95</url>
<year>1995</year>
</incollection>
</cool>
```

code:

```
val corrupt_records_handled_DF=spark.read.format("xml").option("rootTag","cool").option("rowTag","incollection").load("/usr/local/inputs/temp.xml")
```

I'm getting it as corrupt record.

Spark version : 2.4.6
packages : com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.9.0

output:

```
scala> val corrupt_records_handled_DF=spark.read.format("xml").option("rootTag","cool").option("rowTag","incollection").load("/usr/local/inputs/temp.xml")
corrupt_records_handled_DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_corrupt_record                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|<incollection mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/acm/kim95/Blakeley95">
<author>Jos&eacute; A. Blakeley</author>
<title>OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.</title>
<pages>69-88</pages>
<booktitle>Modern Database Systems</booktitle>
<url>db/books/collections/kim95.html#Blakeley95</url>
<year>1995</year>
</incollection>|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

can you folks help me with this?

Answer (score -2):

your problem is located here . in xml file, for a empty node, you have to write  or 
Note that in IntelliJ, when you open this xml file, you can highlight this error in red.

Hecham